Tankless gas heater ignites when cold water flow is turned off
I'm at my wit's end here. I have a 12L tankless gas geyser that has been giving me all kinds of trouble from installation. Most of this was resolved by the manufacturer's helpful technician. HOWEVER....
In the following scenario's, the hot water is NOT running:
I open any coldwater tap inside or outside the house, or I flush the toilet, and once the cold water flow stops (tap is closed or toilet cistern is full) and my geyser ignites for a second or two, and then switches off again.
No one seems to have an explanation or solution other than I need to install a non-return valve, which I already have installed. A plumber even suggested that I replace the valve with a ball-type nrv, which I also did. Problem hasn't changed at all?
Has anyone experienced the same problem, and if so were you able to get it resolved?
Many thanks
Shawn

it reacts to the pressure fluctuation

Please post more information such as a photo and model numbers
